# Displaying multiple subpages in MS Office OneNote

Tags: microsoft-office

Is there some way to set up the view in MicroSoft OneNote so that all of the subpages of a page can be displayed simultaneously on one page?

Answer (score 0):

As far as default functionality is concerned, no, that isn't possible. However, you could just copy all the content from each subpage into a master page which would accomplish the same thing. You could also check out Onetastic and create a macro to simplify the copy process.